# Adding child to parent in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model and would like to add children to parents through a form when the parent is edited, I am using the Ancestry gem to create a hierarchy (previously asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142785/form-for-adding-children-using-ancestry-gem) but was maybe a bit unclear). I have tried to use virtual attributes to do give the child-to-be-added an attribute, in the user model I have added an new_child to attr_accessor. Now that the parent user is updated I would like to update the child user (adding the parent). I have tried this in the controller but get an undefined method `update_attributes!' for nil:NilClass error, any suggestions for how solve this problem?

user_controller.rb

```
def update
   User.find_by_id(@new_child).update_attributes!(parent_id: @user)
   ...
end
```

user.rb

```
attr_accessible :new_child
attr_accessor :new_child
```

edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :new_child, "Add child (enter child id)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :new_child %>
  <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn" %>            
<% end %>
```